# Plot empty DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Can I force empty DataFrame to plot? I'm filling `xlim` and `yticks`, I don't see why it should not be possible.

```
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time, ch, 0]
Index: []

>>> df.plot(x="time", y="ch",
            ax=ax,
            ...
            xlim=(start, end),
            yticks=range(ymin, ymax+1))
...
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Also tried to plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`, but it ends with `KeyError` if I pass `ax`.

```
>>> plt.plot()
>>> plt.axes(ax)
...
KeyError: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x00000000060E6BE0>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of plotting this empty df?

Comment: So my GUI looks the same no matter the input data.

Comment: Well, you could test for the emptiness and call `plot()` accordingly ? (`df.plot()` or `plt.plot()`)

Comment: Tried too, but it ends with `KeyError` if I pass `ax`.

Comment: If you to make an empty plot in an already existing figure with subplots, you can either pass if df is empty or plot something otherwise. Or if you just want to set the axis, just do `ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()`. But I guess your question is unclear. What do you have so far in your GUI and what do you expect ?

Comment: It appears that ax doesn't exist to begin with. You should also be calling ax.plot directly instead of plt.plot